# "Extra data" error trying to load a JSON file with Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load the following JSON file, named `archived_sensor_data.json`, into Python:

```
[{"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475899932.677}, "id": "40898785-6e82-40a2-a36a-70bd0c772056", "name": "Elizabeth Woods"}][{"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475899932.677}, "id": "40898785-6e82-40a2-a36a-70bd0c772056", "name": "Elizabeth Woods"}, {"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475816130.812}, "id": "2f896308-884d-4a5f-a8d2-ee68fc4c625a", "name": "Susan Wagner"}]
```

The script I'm trying to run (from the same directory) is as follows:

```
import json
reconstructed_data = json.load(open("archived_sensor_data.json"))
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 164 - line 1 column 324 (char 163 - 323)
```

I'm not sure where this is going wrong, because from [www.json.org](http://www.json.org/) it seems like valid JSON syntax for an array of dictionaries. Any ideas what is causing the error?

Comment: You have two arrays, not one json object. Look around the characters  `}][{`

Comment: You can validate the JSON here, if you wanted.  http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a valid json;
There are two list in here;
one is

```
[{"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475899932.677}, "id": "40898785-6e82-40a2-a36a-70bd0c772056", "name": "Elizabeth Woods"}]
```

and the other one

```
[{"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475899932.677}, "id": "40898785-6e82-40a2-a36a-70bd0c772056", "name": "Elizabeth Woods"}, {"timestamp": {"timezone": "+00:00", "$reql_type$": "TIME", "epoch_time": 1475816130.812}, "id": "2f896308-884d-4a5f-a8d2-ee68fc4c625a", "name": "Susan Wagner"}]
```

You can see the validation error in here;
http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=569644c48d5753ceb21daf66483d80cd